# Same .htaccess on 2 servers, only working on one

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

**Scenario**

I am working with two servers both running apache. An identical `.htaccess` is working on one server and not the other.

**Code**

```
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
Require user jackson
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All

<FilesMatch "^ads\.txt$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

Satisfy Any
```

**Question**

Anonymous visitors are able to see `ads.txt` on server A without logging in, however, they'll see `401 (unauthorized)` on server B. What could be the reason or what can I do to troubleshoot further?

**Extra**

- If I switch to `Allow from All` on line 6 the ads.txt is STILL blocked on server B by a `401`. If I comment out the `FilesMatch` condition then it's unblocked. This only escalates the confusion..
- Server B has a `.htaccess` in the parent directory. Setting it to `Allow from All` didn't have any effect.
- Both files are `664` and belong to a group apache has access to.

Comment: same .htaccess doesn't mean both servers are identical in terms of other aspect. e.g. directory permissions

Comment: Both files are `664` and belong to a group apache has access to - just added to "Extra"

Comment: Which Apache version are on both servers?

Comment: @MrWhite `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)` on B but w server A it seems I don't have the creds to see the current OS or apache details - Per how it operates it's definitely apache2 on some linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

Are both servers running the same linux distribution and version and are both running the same version of Apache?

Although the files might have the same permissions (664 and same owner/group), is the full path accessible on both servers? Maybe one of the subfolders has too restrictive permissions.